# AD additional attribute synced to AAD extension attribute not showing up on AAD user object

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Can someone please help me with the following, thanks in advance

I setup AD Connect in a LAB and my LAB Active Directory users are syncing OK to my LAB Azure AD

I then went through the Azure AD Connect setup wizard a second time to sync 'custom sync options'  and chose 'Directory Extension Attribute Sync' and chose to sync two additional attributes (for testing), I chose the Active Directory attributes 'adminCount' and 'carLicense'  I have a domain admin user called Craig who has his adminCount attribute set to 1 and I added a value for carLicense

When I check **Get-ADSyncGlobalSettings**

I can see under **Microsoft.OptionalFeature.DirectoryExtensionAttributes** the carLicense and adminCount listed (among other attributes) therefore looks like AD Connect should sync these two attributes from AD to Azure AD right?

However even after restarting AD Connect and doing a delta sync too I still do not see these attributes on my Azure AD User when I do **Get-AzureADUser -SearchString Graig | select -ExpandProperty extensionproperty**

There is no sign of the adminCount or carLicense attributes or their values in the output

Please advise, where I am going wrong?

Do I need an Azure AD P2 license or something to sync additional built in active directory attributes?

I also set up a separate custom rule to sync an AD attribute to extension13 of the AAD user class.

The above appears in the Metaverse under AD Connect OK (with the correct values populated)

However, there are not appears in the AAD User object, as above any idea please

Thanks in advance

CXMelga

Comment: Hey, my knowledge in AD is very limited. But I once faced an issue where AD Connect fails to sync a DirectoryObject to Azure AD. Turned out it had an attribute with a very long string value. therefore, AD Connect failed to sync the object. Take a look at your attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also set up a separate custom rule to sync an AD attribute to extension13 of the AAD user class.

If you sync the extension attribute to the `extensionAttribute13`, you are unable to get that via Azure AD powershell `Get-AzureADUser`.

The [`extensionAttribute13`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onpremisesextensionattributes?view=graph-rest-1.0) belongs to [`onPremisesExtensionAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) which is a property just for the [`User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) object in Microsoft Graph, but the `AzureAD` powershell calls [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog), the `onPremisesExtensionAttributes` property is not a property of the [`User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity) in AAD Graph.

So if you want to get the attribute, here are two solutions for you to refer.

**1**.Use the Microsoft Graph - [`Get a user`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to do that, use the query as below in the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#). Or if you want to use powershell to do that, your option is to call the MS Graph in powershell with [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6), a sample [here](https://www.vrdmn.com/2017/05/authenticating-to-microsoft-graph-api.html).

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<object-id of the user>?$select=onPremisesExtensionAttributes
```

[image]

**2**.When you use the Azure AD Connect to sync, edit outbound synchronization rule like below. In your case, it should be like `extension_3e2cd06ca3494546888b069a891b4bb6_adminCount`. See this [link](https://ronnydejong.com/2015/09/14/use-custom-attributes-for-automatically-populate-azure-ad-dynamic-group-memberships/) for more details.

[image]

Then you will be able to get the extension attribute with the command as below(I recommend you not to use `-SearchString` parameter, sometimes it returns nothing.)

```
Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId <object-id of the user>
```

Or

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId <object-id of the user> | select -ExpandProperty extensionproperty
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, everyone and especially Joy Wang, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out. 
I will try out your suggestions Joy

Comment: Hello Again 
Joy, I tried your solutions above, but unfortunately, they did not work as expected. I cannot seem to copy and paste images here to illustrate further so I have place a word document on my onedrive to show what I mean at the following location

https://1drv.ms/w/s!AqL5zUwOWToZgbYFlezdHFevRQig8w?e=mcfGiW

Can you please take a look at the screenshots and explanations in the word document and let me know what you think?

Thanks

Comment: @AUser You tried which solution? If you use the second one, did you `edit outbound synchronization rule`, and choose the first option as `extension_xxxxxxxx_adminCount` like the screenshot in my reply? Could you follow this link to try again? https://ronnydejong.com/2015/09/14/use-custom-attributes-for-automatically-populate-azure-ad-dynamic-group-memberships/

Comment: @AUser Also check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/user-provisioning-sync-attributes-for-mapping , follow it to try again, don't miss any step.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply Joy, I will look over your reply and update this post once I have gone through your replies

Comment: Thank you for your help Joy, I have resolved the problem now, with your help :)