# Exporting Azure users with extension attribute

Tags: azure, active-directory

Our account department has asked me a question, that I didn't know the answer to.

Must first tell, that we are on a hybrid environment.

Each month I export our users from Azure, to forward it to the accounting department. Which then distributes the license costs for the internal department the user works in. 
Our problem is that the department field in AD, isn't detailed enough as some of the departments have sub-departments. These sub-departments isn't mentioned in the field, cause we use that for our e-mail signatures, and we do not want to have these in official communication.

The accounting department is asking, if we can enrich the export, with a department number.

So is there a way, where I can use some of the other fields on the users AD object, that gets synchronized to Azure, and again gets into the export from the Active users list?

Answer (score 0):

If your users are synchronized from on-premise AD to Azure AD, you could use the [`onPremisesExtensionAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onpremisesextensionattributes?view=graph-rest-1.0) property of the [user object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties). There are fifteen `extensionAttributes`  in `onPremisesExtensionAttributes`, you can store the department number in any one of them.

After storing them, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/user-provisioning-sync-attributes-for-mapping) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58689822/ad-additional-attribute-synced-to-aad-extension-attribute-not-showing-up-on-aad/58706356#58706356) to sync the attributes to Azure AD and get the attributes.